# except session any other option to keep data in spring MVC application

Tags: java, performance, session, spring-mvc

I am developing Online Examination software, where thousands of students can give online exam from their college/school at a same time. So considering concurrent hits and server performance i am finding the different and best way to store some exam related data:

In application each student will get questions randomly. I am thinking to store student wise questions in `session` but i am worried about storing such a large (question its options) data in `session`.

Consider an scenario let each student will have 30 ques and in a single slot 10k students are there. Then `session` object will become too big, isn’t it?

Also there are some settings/configurations related to exam which i want to keep ready (i don't want to fetch the configurations from DB each time).

Comment: I don't think storing such large data (question its options) in `session` is good idea.why you are not ready to fetch each question along with its options each time from server?

Comment: I think you might be underestimating the performance of a database server.

Comment: The concern about fetching question and options each time from server is web server will become too busy to serve the requests as i already mention there will be thousands of students for exam and as @Bart said performance of database server is also get down.

Comment: @Amogh How you gonna store answer or option selected by student? Have you considered Question or option having images means i have seen some online exam portal where question or answer are in image format,in such scenario how you will store images in `session`. I don't think question and options are small object as like `user obj` to store in `session`.

Comment: If you are afraid the shear number of active students will DOS your server you should scale up. My guess is that you're acting on the assumption alone without any testing. You should build your application and load test it. If problems arise then you should fix them.

Comment: @Bart,Thanks,Today only i tested my application using `JMeter`.I recorded exam scenario in it i sent with 2000 users in 5 mins.Application is deloyed on Ubuntu 64 bit server with 4 GB RAM and 4 CPU's.currently i put question and options in session and each time when student submits answer i store answer in DB and take next question from `session`.Memory by `glassfish` service is between `63-89%`..what else i do?

Comment: @user1372488 currently in application i am storing student answer in DB as he submits it.Before submiting mark calculation is also done for that question.And yes,question or option having `images` will be possible in application.

Answer (score 1):

> Consider an scenario let each student will have 30 ques and in a single slot 10k students...

I suppose some students get the same question. In case you really  have 300k different questions, you can stop reading now.

> In application each student will get questions **randomly**. I am thinking to store student wise questions in session

I guess you don't need to store anything then. Generate a single random `masterSeed`, take a `studentId`, and compute `seed = secureHash(masterSeed, studentId)`. Use this `seed` for selecting the questions. Recompute if needed.

Concerning storing the questions, use the database and caches as usual, forget the session.

#### Requested details about question selection

The answer to "Can you please provide some more exposure to selecting questions using seed and caches" is "actually no". Why?

- Whatever randomized algorithm the OP uses for choosing the question will work the same with my above proposal. Just create `new Random(seed)` (with the seed coming from above) and run the same algorithm.<sup>1</sup>
- All the caching magic a web and database servers are capable of, applies here too. My point is that *there's nothing to gain by storing the questions in the session*. Quite the opposite:

  - The data stored in the session are "dirty" and the server has to serialize them in case of low memory.
  - Whenever the same question for two students gets deserialized, you have two distinct pieces of data taking twice as much memory as before.

So you have more IO (a cached data can be simply discarded), more memory consumption, and you can't use the database server's memory in case it runs on a different machine.

---

<sup>1</sup> This can get complicated in case the algorithm is *not really random* and tries to choose different question for students sitting next to each other, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Um! This sounds interesting!! Can you please provide some more exposure to selecting questions using `seed` and caches?

Comment: Thanks for update and this is really sounds interesting! I will do changes and get on this later but as @user1372488 said if in future question and options are in image format then how session or caches will work?

Comment: @Amogh: What is the total amount of data you need? You have 4 GB, that's enough for maybe thousands of images. If the memory doesn't suffice, maybe the disk is fast enough to serve the images as needed (a latency of 1 second should be OK and a cheap disk throughput is some hundreds of MB/s).

Comment: @maaartinus So your idea is if images are get added in questions then that data(images) will also keep in cache?

Comment: @Amogh: My main idea is to avoid storing huge data in the session as it can only make things worse. The questions (with or without images) are immutable and (I guess) shared across some students - this looks like they don't belong into the session. First I'd try if the server can handle it without any quirks; otherwise I'd try some in-memory caching.

Comment: okay,What you are saying @maaartinus is correct.I am using `mysql Rand()` to allocate random questionid to students so there may be some questions which is shared across multiple students.What i do now first i ll try for cacheing of data (questions without images) now and load test again,is this okay?

Comment: @maaartinus to be very frank i am still confuse about your `"masterSeed"` logic (Sorry!!).What i understood is- Use `masterSeed` instade `mysql Rand()` to randomize the questions across the students then cache that data..Correct?

Comment: @Amogh: The `masterSeed` is actually pretty unimportant! It was just to show that you need no *per student* data at all (as you can re-generate a `seed` from the `masterSeed` and `studentId` anytime and generate everything else from the `seed`. If you're still confused then simply forget it. Just store the `questionId`s anywhere (it's small) so you can fetch the questions afterwards.

Comment: @Amogh: I wouldn't use `mysql Rand()` for anything... what if you want to ensure that no nearby students get the same question? The database gives you zero flexibility here and you don't need it for this. Get the range from the DB and generate a random id in Java.

Comment: Okay.It's getting to long comments on this..I'll try to put data in cache as @maaartinus said and get back on this.currently there is no need to check that no nearby students get the same question :).Thanks for your time to time guideance.